# Entity Framework como agregar datos por defecto a mi tabla con .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, framework

Hola estoy creando un modelo y me gustaría que cuando hago la migración y se crean las tablas estas tengan unos valores por defecto

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: En si lo que debes hacer es un `seed`. Acá una guía https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding

Comment: El probleam es que mi proyecto esta construido en .netframework 4.7.2 y toda la informacion del seed que encuentro es para .net core. Por ejemplo el tutorial que me muestras usan el HasData y en .netframework no existe.